# Magento get product information on view page

Tags: php, magento, mage

This is probably a very easy question. (many of mine seem to be)

But how do you get basic product information to be echo'd on product view page.  Here are the things I am trying to access:

- Inventory Stock Quantity
- Restock Date

Essentially I'm looking for something like

```
<?php echo $_product->getQty(); ?>
```

Except that would only give the in cart quantity, but it doesn't even work.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this to get product quantity

```
<?php echo (int) Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($_product)->getQty(); ?>
```

Comment: That does seem to work in most cases. Thank you!  Now what about the Restock Date.  On the magento backend user-panel, each product has another tab named after the web design company that made our site.  How would I access attributes on that tab.

Comment: For example it has general, prices, meta information, CustomTabName

Answer (score 0):

Since the restock date is a custom attribute you can simply edit it from the admin (*Catalog > Attributes > Manage Attributes*) and change it's "Visible on Product View Page on Front-end" to "Yes".

Answer (score 0):

```
$_stock_data = $_product->getStockItem()->getData();
print_r($_stock_data);
```

So to get quantity.

```
$_product->getStockItem()->getQty();
```

*Courtesy : Jagi Yadav*

Answer (score -1):

If you are looking to get an attribute on that product you can do it like this:

$_product->getColor()
where Color is attribute name.
Or you can call an attribute using this syntax:

$this->htmlEscape($_product->getData(color));

Comment: he is looking for a way to get stock data. not any product data via magic methods.